# How to ask ALSA to output to a specific Pulseaudio sink?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

Various examples on the web, as well as the output of `aplay -L`, indicate that I have an ALSA device named "pulse" which I can use as a shim to let ALSA-compliant applications output to Pulseaudio.

Presumably this outputs to the default PulseAudio sink by default.

How do I create an ALSA device which outputs to another PulseAudio sink?

Answer (score 2):

The source tarball for "alsa-plugins" contains a file which describes the options to the `pulse` PCM plugin:

```
alsa-plugins-1.1.1/doc/README-pulse
```

It lists the following parameters for PCM devices

- **server** (name of the PulseAudio server to use)
- **device** (name of the PulseAudio source or sink)
- **fallback** (PCM to use when we can't connect to PulseAudio server)

The mixer control plugin (e.g. `ctl.X`) also accepts the parameters "source" and "sink", which are not recognized by the PCM plugin.

The file `alsa-plugins-1.1.1/pulse/pcm_pulse.c` also lists the additional parameters for PCM plugins:

- **handle_underrun**
- **comment**

Here is an example of an `~/.asoundrc` which outputs to a named PulseAudio sink using the `device` parameter:

```
pcm.pulse_test {
    type pulse;
    device "my_sink";
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can also easily switch the Pulseaudio sink of the ALSA application with `pavucontrol` or `pamcd`; there's no need to specify one `pulse` endpoint in `~/.asoundrc` for every Pulseaudio sink you want to use. I think the Pulseaudio connection database even restores the sink that was last used for a specific ALSA application, though I may remember that wrongly.

Comment: Do you know of a way to specify the device as part of the PCM string, just like you can with `plughw:0,0`? For example `ecasound -o alsa,pulse:device=DEV`, but that doesn't work...

Comment: You cannot specify the device when you use the ALSA wrapper to access Pulseaudio. You need an application that can access Pulseaudio directly to do that.

Comment: It works for me to specify the device as part of the PCM string with Linux 5.11.4-arch1-1.
Tested it like this `speaker-test -D pulse:tunnel.tweek.local.alsa_output.usb-145f_USB_Audio-00.analog-surround-71` and `speaker-test -D pulse:alsa_output.pci-0000_31_00.4.analog-stereo`. But some applications seem to not like it (e.g. crash).